# Laravel: Catch all routes that does not have /api/ segment

Tags: regex, laravel

I need to catch all routes, except those that have /api/ segment in them.
I know how to catch every single route

```
Route::any('{all}', 'AngularController@serveFrontend')->where('all', '(.*)');
```

But what do I need to change so that my api routes aren't captured by this string ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can catch all routes where the path does not start with `api`

```
Route::any('{all}', 'AngularController@serveFrontend')->where('all', '^(?!api).*$');
```

Or simply leave your catchall as the last route and it'll work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I have placed two ::any catch strings. One in end of /api/ group, and one in end of routes file. Now missing api routes returns JSON, and all missing frontend routes returns default html.

Answer (score 3):

For multiple exceptions, you may use `|` identifier: (eg nova)

```
Route::get('/{all}','AngularController@serveFrontend')->where('all','^(?!api|nova).*$');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just place route(s) with `/api/` segment before this one and it will work as you want. All API related URLs will be processes by first route, everything else will be processed with second one.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch all the routes except those that start `/api`

```
Route::any('{any}', [UserController::class,'index'])->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
```