# Laravel: catch all routes where the path does not start with api

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I use [this](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel-vue-cli-3) starter `Laravel + Vue SPA` where I have such a router in web.php:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

But when I make a request for an api with a nonexistent url, I would like to return a response via

```
Route::fallback(function() {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found!'], 404);
});
```

This route does not work and instead of it the request goes to this route:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

I understand I need to change `->where('any', '.*');` but not sure how.

Comment: This type of url redirect every request to `SpaController@index` to make laravel+vue SPA

Comment: You will have to use Vue-router's feature to show 404 page

Comment: But how can I make `Route::fallback` work? I need to show 404 for api

Comment: it will work if it is at top

Comment: Place fallback route above to spa route

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of this

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

I use

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
```

I was helped by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542823/5286034).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show 404 page in laravel vue spa then use vue-router's 404 feature

vue routes should have a route like this

```
routes:[
    {path:'*',component:NotFound,name:'NotFound'},
...
]
```

NotFound component can be designed to show 404 page.

If you still want to make your fallback route work then place it above SPA route.

```
Route::fallback(function() {
return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found!'], 404);
});

Route::get('/{any}','SpaController@index')->where('any','.*');
```

Comment: This does not work because the route is always found, '.*' means all routes. I need to specify instead of '.*' another expression so that the route does not propagate for api.

Comment: then I think you should use vue-router approach

Comment: See my answer, it seems you have misunderstood me.

Answer (score 0):

I use `get('/{any}'`  together with a where condition regular expression `('^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.-]*')` : to catch "any" route apart from the api route:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.-]*');
```

so if I call any nonexistent API URL I get the laravel 404 error page.